# How to calculate distance from a pixel in the CIELAB color space to its corresponding Maximum RGBY

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, colors, javacv

I have a RGB image and i converted it into CIELAB color space. the next step is, I need to compute the corresponding R,G,B,Y values respectively from the the CIELAB image, which means from the CIELAB image i should get one image for Red, Green, Blue,Yellow after computing their corresponding pixel values from the CIELAB image.

so, for each pixel in the CIELAB image i am getting its value on the A-Axis and the B-Axis, but what i do not know how to do is, how to compute the distance from the pixel value on the a-Axis and the B-Axis to the Maximum red vlaue for an example. in other words, if the pixel in the CIELAB color space at row = 3 and col = 3 has A-AxisValue = 100 and B-AxisVal = 60, then how can I calculate the distance from this pixel to the Maximum Red color value on the CIELAB color space.

the question in other words, how to clculate the distance from a current pixel in the CIELAB color spce to the maximum R,G,B and Y in the same color space? to solve this, i need the maximum coordinates of R,G,B,Y on the CIELAB color system

Comment: What absolute color space are you trying to convert to? CIELAB to RGB (and RGBY which is just a redundant representation of RGB) conversions are device dependant.

Comment: @Raab70 actually i am not tryin g to convert to anothe color sytem. i have CIELAB image, and as you know, the LAB-images has +-aAxis, and +-bAxis. and on the CIELAB color space the R is the opponent for G and vice versa and Y is the opponent to B and vice versa, what i want to know is, in the CIELAB color space, what is the maximum value for each of R,G,B,Y,? or in other words, what is the value on the CIELAB color space that represents the maximum/absolute Red color for an example. i wish i am clear

Comment: it is defined in your implementation of the RGB->CIELAB conversion. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), "The scaling and limits of the a* and b* axes will depend on the specific implementation of Lab color, as described below, but they often run in the range of ±100 or -128 to +127."

Comment: @Raab70 kindly please would you mind having alook at this publication page 15, the name of the section is "color channel", and tell me why they specified the maximum Red on the a and b axis to 255,127? the publicatin is here: http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Simone_Frintrop/publication/228976043_Computational_Visual_Attention/links/00b7d535a47c13d344000000.pdf

Comment: Generally the resolution of each channel would be chosen based on the available fidelity of the device which will be used to reproduce it. For questions that specific I would recommend you contact the author for clarification.